# Is there a way to INSERT values into one table, then UPDATE values in another table? mySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to Insert Values into table A, then Update a value in table B in a single stored procedure.

```
UPDATE Devices
SET Devices.Available = 1
WHERE Devices.DeviceID = DeviceID;

INSERT INTO Withdrawals(Withdrawals.DeviceID, 
                        Withdrawals.StudentID, 
                        Withdrawals.WithdrawalDate,
                        Withdrawals.Deadline)
VALUES(DeviceID, 
       StudentID,
       CURRENT_DATE,
       DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY));
```

Each query works when executed individually. I've researched how to do this and believe its the right way but for some reason its not executing?

Comment: Are you after a transaction?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Is there a problem with ACID?

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx/

Comment: Why does the question insert then update and the code update then insert?